# Screenfilling not working

Tags: python, pygame

So I fell against this weird problem where I can't fill the screen. My code is

```
#Import all modules
import pygame
import random
import math
import time

#Colors
BLACK = ( 0, 0, 0)
WHITE = ( 255, 255, 255)
GREEN = ( 0, 255, 0)
RED = ( 255, 0, 0)
ORANGe = (255, 115, 0)
YELLOW = (242, 255, 0)
BROWN = (115, 87, 39)
PURPLE = ( 298, 0, 246)
GRAY = ( 168, 168, 168)
BLUE = ( 0, 0, 255)
pygame.init()
# Clock
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
#Screen
screenx = 1000
screeny = 700
screen = pygame.display.set_mode([screenx,screeny])

#Title
pygame.display.set_caption("OUCH Version 0.1")
#Classes (if any)

#Variables
sound = True
password = False
titlescreen = True

#Booleans




#Sounds



#The graphics


#Positions


#Time management
fps = 60

#Other Things


#Main Loop__________________________________________________
done = False

while not done:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True

    if titlescreen:

        screen.fill(WHITE)





    #Flip the Display
    pygame.display.flip
    clock.tick(fps)

#If done

pygame.quit()
```

I just updated to python 3.4, may that be the problem. Or am I overlooking something. I'm trying to fill the screen white but every time I run it the screen always turns out to be black. Thank you for any help. :)

What I have tried__________

I tried looking if theirs something with the color WHITE, but when I try any other color it does not work. I also tried just screen filling with ought the Boolean yet that doesn't work either. I have also tried not doing if titlescreen:, but if titlescreen == True: then bla bla

Comment: Yea, I think you have to downgrade your python version to use pygame

Comment: Also pygame.display.flip() is a function. Put parentheses after it.

Comment: Wow. Thank you.. It worked Jerrybibo. I guess I should be more focused. And I do have the proper version of pygame..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to put brakets:

```
pygame.display.flip()
```

Comment: Although this may answer the question, be more descriptive about it.

Comment: @Bond - Java Bond What could i tell more for this little mistake?

Comment: Do read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) --> `Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better.` For future visitor your answer is _expected_ to provide instructions in general how to debug / identify issues etc. in similar situations.